# Autonest an array

Tags: code-golf, array, balanced-string

Everybody loves nested lists! However, sometimes it's hard to make a nested list. You have to decide if you want to nest it deeper, or if you need to nest it shallower. So for your challenge, you must "Autonest" a list. To autonest a list, compare every pair of items in the list.

- If the second item is smaller, separate the two elements by inserting closing and opening brackets between them, like this:

  ```
    } {
  {2 , 1}
  ```

  For example, `{2, 1}` becomes `{2}, {1}`, and `{3, 2, 1}` becomes `{3}, {2}, {1}`
- If the second item is the same, then change nothing. For example, `{1, 1, 1}` stays the same, and `{2, 1, 1, 1}` would become `{2}, {1, 1, 1}`.
- If the second item is larger, then nest every following item one level deeper. For example, `{1, 2}` would become `{1, {2}}` and `{1, 2, 3}` would become `{1, {2, {3}}}`

## The Challenge

You must write a program or function that takes in a list of numbers, and returns the same list after being autonested. Take this input in your languages native list format (or the closest alternative) or as a string. You do not have to use curly braces like I did in my examples. You can use whichever type of brackets are most natural in your language, as long as this is consistent. You can safely assume the list will only contain integers. You can also assume the list will have at least 2 numbers in it. Here is some sample IO:

```
{1, 3, 2}                         -->   {1, {3}, {2}}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}                -->   {1, {2, {3, {4, {5, {6}}}}}}
{6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}                -->   {6}, {5}, {4}, {3}, {2}, {1}
{7, 3, 3, 2, 6, 4}                -->   {7}, {3, 3}, {2, {6}, {4}}
{7, 3, 1, -8, 4, 8, 2, -9, 2, 8}  -->   {7}, {3}, {1}, {-8, {4, {8}, {2}, {-9, {2, {8}}}}}
```

Standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Can we take the input in our language's string format?

Comment: What is the max size of the integer?

Comment: @thepiercingarrow I don't really care too much. It won't be anything ridiculous. You should be able to at least handle `[-100, 100]` but I'm not planning on giving gigantic inputs.

Comment: "If the second item is smaller, then nest all following elements one level higher, by inserting a closing bracket. Then, to make sure all the brackets stay matched, insert an opening bracket. For example, `{2, 1}` becomes `{2}, {1}`" How is that one level higher? One level higher would be `{2}, 1`. What you have is the same level.

Comment: @msh210 Yeah, that was a poor explanation. Is the current phrasing better?

Comment: Yes, except that now it sounds like the result has to be a string, whereas previously I thought it could be a nested array of arrays.

Comment: If I return a string, does it need to include spaces between the commas and braces?

Comment: @TuukkaX No, it just has to be a valid array representation.

Comment: @mbomb007 yes, you should handle negative numbers.

Comment: Can I use space separated list?

Comment: In my answer: _the output would not be interpreted as a nested list in MATL. It would in other languages, and it satisfies the output specification in the challenge._ Is that accepted? That is, produce a string that can be interpreted as nested list/array (for example in other other languages), even if it doesn't have that meaning in the chosen language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>48</s> 43 bytes

```
YY_XKx"@K<?93]44@K-?91]@XKV]v93Gd0>sQY"h4L)
```

This uses square brackets in input and output. The output has commas without spaces as separators.

Note that the output would not be interpreted as a nested list in MATL. It would in other languages, and it satisfies the output specification in the challenge.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WVlfWEt4IkBLPD85M100NEBLLT85MV1AWEtWXXY5M0dkMD5zUVkiaDRMKQ&input=WzcsIDMsIDEsIC04LCA0LCA4LCAyLCAtOSwgMiwgOF0)

#### Explanation

```
YY_XKx   % Push -inf. Copy to clipboard K (represents previous input entry). Delete
"        % Take numerical array implicitly. For each entry:
  @K<    %   Is current entry less than the previous one?
  ?93]   %   If so, push 93 (ASCII for ']')
  44     %   Push 44 (ASCII for comma)
  @K-    %   Is current entry different from the previous one?
  ?91]   %   If so, push 91 (ASCII for '[')
  @XKV   %   Push current entry, copy into clipboard K, convert to string
]        % End for each
v        % Concat vertically all stack contents, converting to char
93       % Push 93 (ASCII for ']') (to be repeated the appropriate number of times)
Gd0>sQ   % Determine how many times the input increases, plus 1
Y"       % Repeat 93 that many times
h        % Concat horizontally with previous string. Gives a row array, i.e. string
4L)      % Remove first char, which is an unwanted comma. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 96 bytes

```
a#b|a<b=",{"|a>b="},{"|1<2=","
f(a:b:c)=show a++a#b++f(b:c)++['}'|a<b]
f[x]=show x++"}"
('{':).f
```

Usage example: `('{':).f $ [7,3,3,2,6,4]` -> `"{7},{3,3},{2,{6},{4}}"`.

As Haskell doesn't have nested lists, I return the result as a string. The nesting algorithm is easy: a) print number, b) if the next number is greater (less, equal), print `,{` ( `},{`, `,`), c) make a recursive call with the rest of the list, d) print `}` if the number is less than the next one, e) enclose everything in `{` and `}`.

Comment: Sorry, I miscount

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 98 bytes

```
p,*i=eval(input())
c=[p]
a=b=[c]
for x in i:
 if x>p:b=c
 if x!=p:c=[];b+=[c]
 c+=[x];p=x
print(a)
```

Example:

```
$ python3 autonest.py <<< "[7, 3, 1, -8, 4, 8, 2, -9, 2, 8]"
[[7], [3], [1], [-8, [4, [8], [2], [-9, [2, [8]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 <strike>197 187 193</strike> 192 bytes

---

Thanks to all the commenters who worked with me on this monstrosity. It was golfed down to 187 bytes until I found a costly bug. However due to the power of <strike>Black Magic</strike> the "runs down to" operator "-->" the byte count is at a healthy 192 bytes.

---

```
String a(int[]b){int l=b.length,d=1,i=0;String c="{";for(;i<l-1;i++)if(b[i]>b[i+1])c+=b[i]+"},{";else if(b[i]<b[i+1]){d++;c+=b[i]+",{";}else c+=b[i]+",";c+=b[l-1];while(d-->0)c+="}";return c;}
```

Comment: Sorry coming right up @Blue

Comment: Also, a couple of tips: 1. You can take the input as an array, rather than a sequence: (int[]b) 2. You can define multiple ints at the same time using commas (int l=b.length,d=1,i=0). 3. You should remove as much whites pace as you can (ex. between variable assignments). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Snippets are meant for javascript code that are meant to be executed in the browser, not challenge submissions. Also, you forgot a space after `length,`

Comment: Oh ok my apologies @Maltysen I will embed it into a full java program. I was just going off of the op saying "function or program" which "returns". So should I refactor this to print my output

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala sorry, should have been more clear. When I said "snippet", I wasn't talking about your code, but rather your formatting. When trying to put code into a post, don't click the "snippet" button, but instead put it in a code block(4 spaces or ctrl-k)

Comment: Oh ok sounds good

Comment: This doesn't add numbers to the result at all if they are equal to the last one.

Comment: @pietu1998 what do you mean?

Comment: `a(new int[]{3,3,3})` returns `{3}`, not `{3, 3, 3}` like it should.

Comment: oh ok fixing now

Comment: `d+=1` could be reduced to `d++`.

Comment: wow... thanks I didnt see that :P

Comment: I cant believe I didnt see that @TuukkaX

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>145</s> 138 bytes

Thanks to Giacomo for 7 bytes!

```
#define P printf(
n;main(c,v,p,t)char**v;{p=-101;for(v++;*v;v++){t=atoi(*v);if(t<p)P"}{");if(t>p)P"{",n++);P"%d ",p=t);}for(;n--;)P"}");}
```

Input is taken through command line arguments and output is given though 
stdout.

sample run:

```
$ ./autonest 7 3 1 -8 4 8 2 -9 2 8
{7 }{3 }{1 }{-8 {4 {8 }{2 }{-9 {2 {8 }}}}}
```

Comment: Try use `t=atoi(*v);` instead of `sscanf(*v,"%d",&t);` [Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

Comment: Use `for(;*++v;)` for save the first 4 and then insted of `if(t<p)P"}{");if(t>p)P"{",n++);` use `t>p?P"}{"):P"{",n++);` for 10 more.

Comment: Building on @GiacomoGarabello [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYxLCsIwEED3nqKMWDL5gFVRcKxeIVco01ayMJUyZFN69rHydu/B4/BmVt33w5jyUMXqO6cso9ll@nQpG/bFC27K2kLLOM2G29AcG7LOFYpw6Cvw3AqitJ1MydiCXh78irAugHd5cl1HWMBn55D@A8ohEG4dkFZVvel546RXvfwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, <s>71</s> 70 bytes

Lists are space separated, with curly braces: `{1 2 3}`. Negative numbers are not supported, so if that's a problem, I'll just delete my answer. Retina + negative numbers = not worth it.

```
\d+
$*
+`\b(1+) (1+\1\b.*)
$1 {$2}
+`\b(1(1+)1*) (\2)\b
$1} {$2
1+
$.0
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCitgXGIoMSspICgxK1wxXGIuKikKJDEgeyQyfQorYFxiKDEoMSspMSopIChcMilcYgokMX0geyQyCjErCiQuMA&input=ezEgMyAyfQp7MSAyIDMgNCA1IDZ9Cns2IDUgNCAzIDIgMX0KezcgMyAzIDIgNiA0fQ)

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

Exploits the fact that the number of last bracket is one more than number of adjacent pair that is increasing in array.

And I don't know `ew` operator before that I had to reimplement.

The input is space separated list delimited by square brackets.

```
'[q~_W=\2ew_{~\_@-g)["["S"]["]=}%@@{~>M']?}%']
```

Explanation

```
'[q~_W=\2ew_{~\_@-g)["["S"]["]=}%@@{~>M']?}%']
'[                                             e# Opening bracket
  q~                                           e# Read the input
    _W=\2ew                                    e# Save the last item and turn array into array of pair of next item and the item itself.
            _                                  e# We need two copies of that item                                       
             {~\_@-g)["["S"]["]=}%             e# Build the "body" that consist of the item and the suitable delimiter, space if equal, opening brace if the first item is the smallest, otherwise, closing bracket and opening bracket.
                                  @@           e# Put in the last item. (It was omitted in previous phase)
                                    {~<']""?}% e# Create the closing bracket as many as the number of increasing adjacent pair
                                               '] e# And one more bracket.
```

I will find out how to do this with actual nested array instead of relying on prettyprinting.

Finally, <s>at par with</s> beaten MATL's answer.

Comment: _Finally, beaten MATL's answer_ Not now :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

```
a=>a.map(r=>l-r?(n=l<r?m:n).push(m=[l=r]):m.push(l),l=a[0],o=n=[m=[]])&&o
```

Explanation: The case of consecutive equal items is easy; the item is just added to the innermost array (here represented by the `m` variable; `n` is the array that contains `m` as its last element, while `o` is the output). For the case of different items, the item always goes in a new innermost array, the only difference being whether that array is a sibling or a child of the previous innermost array. For extra golfiness I set up the arrays so that the initial item counts as a consecutive equal item.